# Using Ternary Operator Inside ng-repeat Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, conditional-operator

It's possible to use a ternary operator inside a `ng-repeat` directive? For example, in certain case I want to load a list instead another, depending of the value of a variable or flag:

```
ng-repeat="$ctrl.darkMode == true ? item in $ctrl.darkList : item in $ctrl.normalList
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way no, but you can do it like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in ($ctrl.darkMode == true ? $ctrl.darkList : $ctrl.normalList)"
```

If your conditions become complicated, you may always use method:

```
ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.getList()"
```